# Kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unkown class but I'm not using that class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

I'm getting an error saying unknown class `<CreateAccountWindow>` when I try and run my program but I've not mentioned CreateAccountWindow in any of my code. I am working on a new project in Pycharm and my old project had a class called CreateAccountWindow.....I assume this must be the cause but I don't know how to fix it.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:

<LoginWindow>:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/callu/OneDrive/Documents/TestApp/main.py", line 16, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 616, in _apply_rule
     cls = Factory_get(cname)
   File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 131, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <CreateAccountWindow>
```

Comment: Don't know kivy, but, does my.kv might perphaps be referencing your old class?

Comment: This is clearly some kind of issue with Pycharm's pathing and/or your code, so you need to debug it on that basis. For a start, does it happen if you delete all the code in your new app? If not, which line of code causes it to start happening? Or if it does happen even with no code in the new app, it must be purely some issue with the code that Pycharm is actually running.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Apologies, added traceback. I also tried deleting all code from my.kv file but still get the same error

Comment: I've deleted all the code and still get the same error message so must be an issue with my setup in Pycharm, shall I repost this question with more of a PyCharm focus?